# Need count of bars (Trading Days) between two dates in Pinescript

Tags: pine-script, trading, pine-script-v5

I have requirement to calculate number of Trading days between today and previous date. This count will exclude all the holidays.

I have achieved the calculation using below script, but the result is correct only for last bar as for previous Bars, bars gets reduced.

My requirement is to have the difference between today and previous date defined as constant which will work from the 1st Bar to last Bar.

Current Output:
Day 1 : 1 Bar,
Day 2 : 2 Bars,
Day 3 : 3 Bars,

Required output : (123 is difference between today and previous date)
Day 1 : 123 Bar,
Day 2 : 123 Bars,
Day 3 : 123 Bars,

```
i_fromYear = input.int(2021, 'From Year', minval=1900)
i_fromMonth = input.int(5, 'From Month', minval=1, maxval=12)
i_fromDay = input.int(18, 'From Day', minval=1, maxval=31)
fromDate = timestamp(i_fromYear, i_fromMonth, i_fromDay, 00, 00)
isGreen = close > open
gCount = ta.cum(time > fromDate and isGreen ? 1 : 0)
rCount = ta.cum(time > fromDate and not isGreen ? 1 : 0)
total = gCount + rCount
```

Adding Original Full Script :

```
//@version=5
indicator('Relative Strength', shorttitle='ARS', max_bars_back=1000, overlay=true)

comparativeTickerId = input.symbol('NSE:NIFTY', title='Comparative Symbol')

startTime = input.time(timestamp("18 May 2021 00:00"), "Start Time")      
endTime   = input.time(timestamp("20 Nov 2021 00:00"), "End Time")  

_barForTime(_t) =>
    var int _bar = na 
    if time_close[1] <= _t and time >= _t
        _bar := bar_index
    _bar
    
firstTime   = _barForTime(startTime)
secondTime  = _barForTime(endTime)

barDelta    = secondTime - firstTime


// ************************************
lenght = barDelta // Change this to 100 to see the actual result, which will be plotted as well as visible in Lable
// ************************************
// Checking the value of barDelta
plot(lenght, title='Days', color=color.blue,  linewidth = 3, style=plot.style_line)
label.new(bar_index, high, style=label.style_none, text='Bar Count\n' + str.tostring(lenght) + '\n')

baseSymbol = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, timeframe.period, close)
comparativeSymbol = request.security(comparativeTickerId, timeframe.period, close)
hline(0, color=color.black, linestyle=hline.style_solid)
res = baseSymbol / baseSymbol[lenght-1] / (comparativeSymbol / comparativeSymbol[lenght-1]) - 1
plot(res, title='ARS', color=res >= 0.0 ? color.lime : color.orange,  linewidth = 2, style=plot.style_area)
```

Answer (score 0):

ashxos, I have updated you with a timestamp input and a function to get the bar_index for a given time. We pass our 2 dates into the functions, and subtract the results.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My Script")

startTime = input.time(timestamp("01 Nov 2021 00:00"), "Start Time")      
endTime   = input.time(timestamp("15 Nov 2021 00:00"), "End Time")        

_barForTime(_t) =>
    var int _bar = na
    if time_close[1] <= _t and time >= _t
        _bar := bar_index
    _bar
    
firstTime   = _barForTime(startTime)
secondTime  = _barForTime(endTime)

barDelta    = secondTime - firstTime
```

Cheers, and best of luck with your trading and coding

Comment: Thanks Bjorgum for your prompt reply. I did try above code and multiple iteration to get the required output. I have included original script with your suggested code implementation. Output is NaN value whereas Im expecting number of Bars between two dates. Am i missing something?

Comment: What time frame are you on? If your specified date is before the first bar on the chart, then we have no bar_index to reference. I get nan on 5min for example, but get a value on daily AFTER date 2

Comment: https://www.tradingview.com/x/VWtzFdVz/ This is daily timeframe

Comment: Hi, Im on Daily Time frame. Specified start date is 18 May 2021, which is recent bar. Can you please check my code to see the expectations on Daily timeframe?

Answer (score 0):

This would be a solution

```
bars_count(start, end)=>
    diff_unix_min = (end - start) / (1000 * 60)
    p = str.tonumber(timeframe.period)
    if timeframe.isdwm
        if timeframe.isdaily
            p := timeframe.multiplier * 60 * 24
        if timeframe.isweekly
            p := timeframe.multiplier * 60 * 24 * 7
        if timeframe.ismonthly
            p := timeframe.multiplier * 60 * 24 * 7 * 4
            
    math.floor(math.max(diff_unix_min / p, 1))
```